# Python Program stops but PID is still active

Tags: python, exit, pid, python-asyncio, autobahn

My program stoped working after about 6 hours, but the `PID` is still active. Also tells me the terminal output when I use `single_process` module and then try to start the programm again:

```
There is an instance of programm.py running. Quit
```

The code of my program is quit simple and just reads the output from a chatroom, but I don't know why it stops working after 6 hours. Can anybody help please?:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner
from asyncio import coroutine
from datetime import datetime
from single_process import single_process


class PoloniexComponent(ApplicationSession):

    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(self.config.realm)

    @coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        def onTrollbox(*args):
            print("type: ", args[0])
            print("msg_number: ", args[1])
            print("user_name: ", args[2])
            print("message: ", args[3])
            print("reputation: ", args[4])
            print(datetime.utcnow())
        try:
            yield from self.subscribe(onTrollbox, 'trollbox')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)


@single_process
def main():
    runner = ApplicationRunner("wss://api.poloniex.com", "realm1")
    runner.run(PoloniexComponent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you saved any output? In particular, look for the `Could not subscribe to topic:` line.

Comment: I have no output, but the PID is still active. Is there a possibility to output everything into a file while it is already active?